# CoffeeScript keeps producing an error when it tries to compile my object

Tags: node.js, object, coffeescript

I have some CoffeeScript code that reads in data from an http stream.

```
https = require 'https'

export.commScore = (IP,from,file)->

  options =
    path: "ctasd/ClassifyMessage_File",
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    method: "POST",
    port: "8088",
    headers:
      "Accept-Language":"en-us",
      "Accept":"*/*",
      "User-Agent":"Commtouch HTTP Client",
      "X-CTCH-PVer": "0000001",
      "X-CTCH-SenderIP": IP,
      "X-CTCH-MailFrom": from,
      "X-CTCH-FileName": file

  stream = http.request(options,(response)->)
```

Every time I try to compile this code I get an error that says:

```
 error: unexpected ,
path: "ctasd/ClassifyMessage_File",
                             ^
```

I have checked CoffeScripts documentation to make sure I was creating this object correctly and Node's http API to make sure I was setting up the stream correctly and everything checked out. I've also tried consulting the all knowing Google to see if anybody had any similia issues but couldn't find anything. Why does CoffeeScript refuse to compile my code?

Comment: Can't reproduce with v1.6.3. Which coffee-script version do you use? Note that `export` is actually a reserved word.

Comment: Compiles fine here, though export is reserved. Also, you don't need trailing commas with that object syntax.

Comment: Also check your whitespace, since CoffeeScript is whitespace-sensitive.  Mixed tabs and spaces are bad practice, for example.

Comment: How are you compiling this code? And what version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: +1 to Arron Dufour. While I was writting my code Sublime had tabbed over a couple of a the values to the correct spot which the compiler didn't like. Manually making sure everything was double spaced fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by Arron Dufour in the comments in the comments. The turns out the compiler didn't like my text editor's automatic indentation. Going through and manually spacing everything fixed the problem.